# how to match a single instance of a character for strsplit?

Tags: r, regex

I need to split function names from a description. They can be like this `pack::fun:description`.
I though a regexp splitting at a single occurence of a character should do, like this:

```
strsplit(c("fun:desc", "pack::fun:desc"), ":{1}")
```

But that splits the second one in three.
What I need is "pack::fun" and "desc".
To make sure the colon is not the problem, I also tried (with the same result):

```
strsplit(c("funzdesc", "packzzfunzdesc"), "z{1}")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know R but it appears you can split on an ever-so-simple regular expression:

```
strsplit(c("fun:desc", "pack::fun:desc"), "\\b:\\b")
  #=> "fun"  "desc"
  #   "pack::fun" "desc"
```

[Demo](https://rextester.com/FLCPIB92295)

Answer (score 0):

An option with regex lookaround to match a `:` where it is not preceded or succeded by a `:`

```
strsplit(c("fun:desc", "pack::fun:desc"), "(?<!:):(?!:)", perl = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "fun"  "desc"

#[[2]]
#[1] "pack::fun" "desc"
```

---

Or using `SKIP`, `FAIL`

```
strsplit(c("fun:desc", "pack::fun:desc"), ":{2,}(*SKIP)(*F)|:", perl = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1] "fun"  "desc"

#[[2]]
#[1] "pack::fun" "desc"
```

Comment: It does seem more complicated than such a simple question warrants, but I guess that's regex. Your solution works perfectly fine, thanks!

Comment: @BerryBoessenkool the issue with `:{1}` is that it is matching the first instance of `:` in all the cases i.e. with more than one `::` as well, creating the confusion in the split

Comment: That now makes total sense all of a sudden. Thanks for explaining!